# Spring Boot Initializr: Maven project or Maven POM?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I want to set up a Spring Boot project using the Spring Initializr (https://start.spring.io) but I was wondering about the difference in the project type you can choose between: Maven Project or Maven POM?

What is exactly the difference between these two types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic difference that you even experience it by selecting the maven project option and say download, you get a maven which includes sample spring boot application

Other case you have existing project and want to add spring boot then you can simply get the configuration to include spring boot artifacts

Comment: I don't even know what this answer is trying to say.

Comment: @Cypher neither me

Answer (score 31):

`Maven POM` creates only the `pom.xml` file.

`Maven Project` creates the `pom.xml` file and a sample project including `src` folder:

```
> src:
    > main:
        > java:
            > com.example:
                Application.java
        > resources:
            application.properties
    > test:
        > java:
            > com.example:
                ApplicationTest.java
> pom.xml
```

Comment: Simple English and strait forward... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Maven Project` is the type which we use to create a common Spring Boot application. It seems `Maven POM` is for downloading build scripts only.

Comment: That's actually wrong. The `Maven POM` option is used to download the build script only. It does not have a `pom` packaging.

Comment: I see, I knew it wrongly! Thanks for pointing that out. Have updated my answer.